# What is Tuple? And tuple vs. List vs. Vector?

Tags: clojure, programming-languages, computer-science

Can you give me a brief description of `Tuple`? And when to use it over `List` and `Vector`?

Answer (score 14):

Tuple is usually represented in Clojure through an associative data structure such as map `{:name "david" :age 35}` or record.

A vector `["david" 35]` offers fast positional access `(= 35 (nth ["david" 35] 1))`, and you can store different types.

A list `("david" 35)` or `("david" "justin" "david")` offers fast access from the head and fast forward traversal. Although it can hold different types it would be most common for it to contain a single type, possibly containing duplicates, in a determined order. Contrast to a set `#{"david" "justin"}` which would contain no duplicates and is optimised for checking membership/presence.

Sorted sets (`sorted-set`) and maps (`sorted-map`) maintain the order of objects using a comparator.

Check out 4clojure and clojuredocs.org. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

When ever you will do more insertion/deletion operations in a data structure you should use a List. When ever in a data structure accessing of variables is very frequent use a vector.

Tuples are objects that pack elements of different types together in a single object, just like pair objects do for pairs of elements, but generalized for any number of elements.
Conceptually, they are similar to plain old data structures (C-like structs) but instead of having named data members, its elements are accessed by their order in the tuple.